# Is it possible to stop the editor from popping up once git prepare-commit-msg hook is called?

Tags: git, git-commit, githooks, pre-commit-hook

I am writing a prepare-commit-msg hook, which interactively prompts the user about some data and creates a commit message in a predefined format. In almost all cases, there is no need for the user to further edit the commit message. So is it possible to inform git not to open the editor once this hook is exited, and directly perform a commit with whatever is in the temporary msg file?

Answer (score 1):

Git looks in a series of places to find the editor to use when the user is expected to interactively configure content in an editor.

*One of these* is the `core.editor` configuration setting, but if none is present it then checks `GIT_EDITOR`, then `VISUAL` (if you're connected to a non-dumb terminal), then `EDITOR`, and finally falls back to a value hardcoded in at compile time (if not overridden by your distro's packaging, the default fallback is `vi`).

The easy answer, then, is to run git with `GIT_EDITOR=:` exported in the environment (`:` is a command identical to `/bin/true`, and this synonym is used in `git/commit.c:run_commit_hook` when git wants to inform a hook that no editor will be used).

That said, that variable needs to be exported *before* the copy of git that invokes your hook is started; you can't set it from within the hook.

Answer (score -2):

In Git, the value of the core.editor configuration controls whether the editor opens or closes once the prepare-commit-msg hook is called. Following the execution of the hook, Git will launch the defined editor if the core.editor configuration is set.

The following actions can be taken to stop the editor from opening following the prepare-commit-msg hook:

1. Temporarily unset core.editor in your hook script:

Inside your prepare-commit-msg hook script, you can unset the core.editor configuration temporarily before you finish the script. This way, Git won't open the editor even if it's configured.

This approach saves the original core.editor setting, unsets it for the duration of your script, and then restores it before exiting.

2. Use git commit with the -m option:

Instead of relying on the default behavior of Git to open the editor, you can use the git commit command with the -m option to specify the commit message directly.

Comment: Surprisingly, I have no 'core.editor' value set. `git config core.editor` exits with exit code 1. It is somehow by default taking nano as the editor.

Comment: Running with `-m ''` is an option. Just checking is there a better option.

Comment: If the git config core.editor command returns an exit code of 1 and you're experiencing the default behavior of Git using nano as the editor, it's possible that there is no global or local core.editor configuration set.

In such cases, Git falls back to a default editor, and on many systems, nano is a commonly used default. To override this behavior, you can set the core.editor configuration to your preferred editor. You can do this globally or on a per-repository basis.

Comment: Try to set global editor:
To set a global editor for all Git repositories, or you can to set an editor for a specific repository

Comment: After setting the core.editor configuration, Git should use your specified editor for commit messages and other interactive operations.

If you don't want to set a specific editor globally or locally and want to prevent the editor from opening during commits altogether, you can use the -m option with the git commit command to provide a commit message

Comment: `core.editor` **overrides** the system default, but if it's unset, git still tries to use the user's general editor preference.